# Universal reference deduction if the argument is address

Tags: c++

Quick query regarding universal references:

Let's say i have this code

```
int q = 10;
auto && wtf = &q;
```

This one compiles fine, but i have no idea what's happening behind the hood. It's taking a reference to an address? isn't that the pointer's job?

I was trying to deduce that `auto&&`'s type will be and i did it by:

```
int & test = &q //error
int && test = &q //error too
```

So what does it become? I need clarification on what's happening and what's the purpose of taking `&` from a universal reference? I am doing this because i am trying to understand std::bind since it can take address or pointers(which is the address of the being pointed aka pointer's value).

Comment: `&q` is a pointer type, so trying to bind it to an `int&` or `int&&` is wrong. From this [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4e204c2ebf801b88), it appears that `decltype(wtf)` becomes `int*&&`, where as is if instead you had assigned wtf to an lvalue expression (maybe a local variable that was a pointer to `q`), you would get `int*&` as the deduced type..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write `&q` you create a temporary value.

> An rvalue [...] is an xvalue, a temporary object (12.2) or subobject thereof, or a value that is not associated with an object.
>   [§ 3.10]

Those are best bound to rvalue references, so

```
auto && wtf = &q;
```

becomes an rvalue reference (`&&` and `&&` stays `&&`) to the type of `&q`. This isn't `int`, it's `int *`. That's why your manual attempt failed.

If you would instead bind to a lvalue, like a local variable, then you get a lvalue reference:

```
int * qptr = &q;
auto && wtf2 = qptr;
// auto becomes (int *)&
// & combined with && becomes &
```

The whole thing can new seen [in action here.](http://ideone.com/zSuYMr)